# background shorthand order in CSS3

Tags: html, css, w3c

There are questions in the HTML5 microsoft certification about the correct order of selectors in the CSS3 **background** shorthand... but I searched, searched... but not found somewhere a valid reference to what is the real order precedence in that shorthand (if any)...

[the W3C recommendation on this matter](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-background) is not very explicit on this subject (at least, is not evident to find that information)....

is ancient CSS2 "see, I rap" (`CIRAP`) acronim was more or less catchy... but even there W3C didn't clearly exprimed a order?!...

What is the meaning for this kind of questions in certifs, if no one knows the standard? What is, finally, the correct order to take in CSS3?

their examples are confusing... by ex, the following makes believe that the order is **`CIRAPCOS`**

> Another example shows equivalence:
>
> ```
> div { background: padding-box url(paper.jpg) white center }
> div {
>     background-color: white;
>     background-image: url(paper.jpg);
>     background-repeat: repeat;
>     background-attachment: scroll;
>     background-position: center;
>     background-clip: padding-box;
>     background-origin: padding-box;
>     background-size: auto auto }
> ```

then the specification mentions:

> Given a valid declaration, for each layer the shorthand first sets the
>   corresponding layer of each of ‘background-**image**’,
>   ‘background-**position**’, ‘background-**size**’, ‘background-**repeat**’,
>   ‘background-**origin**’, ‘background-**clip**’ and ‘background-**attachment**’ to
>   that property's initial value, then assigns any explicit values
>   specified for this layer in the declaration. Finally
>   ‘background-**color**’ is set to the specified color, if any, else set to
>   its initial value.

so, this is how we obtain **`IPSROClACo`**

Comment: In my estimation Microsoft is in no position to certify anyone for HTML5 support :P

Answer (score 15):

Is is explicitely written :

**Value:**

```
[ <bg-layer> , ]* <final-bg-layer>
```

**Where:**

```
<bg-layer> = 
       <bg-image> 
    || <position> [ / <bg-size> ]? 
    || <repeat-style> 
    || <attachment> 
    || <box>{1,2} 
<final-bg-layer> = 
       <bg-image> 
    || <position> [ / <bg-size> ]? 
    || <repeat-style> 
    || <attachment> 
    || <box>{1,2} 
    || <'background-color'>
```

An example, which give us **IPSRABC** :

```
background: 
    url("content.jpg") 
    left top / 200px 70px
    no-repeat
    scroll
    content-box content-box
    white;
/* or */
background-image: url("content.jpg") ;
background-position: left top;
background-size: 200px 70px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: scroll;
background-clip: content-box;
background-origin: content-box;
background-color: white;
```

If you want a mnemonic for it, here is one (and ya, I'm fully opened to any better sentence !) :

> I pee a sir, Abby ! See ? (IPSRABC)

Note : you can put `background-repeat` before `background-position / background-size`, which give you **IRPSABC**.

Comment: A rather less catchy `IPSRABC` then!

Comment: as for me, this is not very explicitely... first, the second, the specification mentions the existance of elements, not a strict order to apply...

Comment: see also the w3schools article(http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp) about `CIRAP`, I can't believe that the order drastically changed to IPSRABC...

Comment: Added to my post, this "lovely" mnemonic, which is already in your head : `I pee a sir, Abby ! See ? (IPSRABC)`

Comment: Not a definitive info, but only for curiosity:  if you open Chrome dev tools, go to a full background property, and press the right arrow, you get your order with clip and origin swapped.

Comment: Mmmh, a bit strange when you know `Co(lor)` is only put in the final `bg-layer`.

Comment: as you can see, the first <bg-layer> is optional... so I am afraid that the order (if any) is hard to find... by the way, in your abbreviation you forget the "Origin"...

Comment: `clip` and `origin` go together, they make the `box` value. I used `B` instead of `ClO` because it's easier to remember, and you don't have to differenciate `Co(lor)` and `Cl(ip)`

Comment: from W3C docs "**first** sets ‘background-origin’ and the second ‘background-clip’": dev.w3.org/csswg/css-backgrounds/#the-background

Comment: My bad, it's `OCl`, not `Clo`.

Answer (score 6):

Q: What are the correct order of <del>selectors</del> values in the CSS3 background shorthand?

A: **any order**

---

**MSDN documentation** for [background](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms530722%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) states...

> Up to five of the following space-delimited values, in **any order**:
>
> - **color** - Any of the range of color values available to the background-color property.
> - **image** - Any of the range of image values available to the background-image property.
> - **repeat** - Any of the range of repeat values available to the background-repeat property.
> - **attachment** -  Any of the range of attachment values available to the background-attachment property.
> - **position** - Any of the range of position values available to the background-position property.

The MSDN documentation lacks the updated CSS3 shorthand properties, but the answer remains...any order

---

Digging further, even **MDN documentation** for [background](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background) (which does include CSS3 syntax) states...

> One or more of the following, in **any order**:
>
> <'background-attachment'> See background-attachment
>
> <'background-clip'> See background-clip
>
> <'background-color'> See background-color
>
> <'background-image'> See background-image
>
> <'background-origin'> See background-origin
>
> <'background-position'> See background-position
>
> <'background-repeat'> See background-repeat
>
> <'background-size'> See background-size. This property must be specified after background-position, separated with the '/' character.

---

A basic example of this: [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/pxfunc/gZTb2/1/)

```
.box1 {
    background-image: url(//placehold.it/100/f00);
    background-position: center center;
    background-color: red;
}
.box2 {
    background: 
        url(//placehold.it/100/f00) /* background-image */
        center center /* background-position */
        red /* background-color */;
}
.box3 {
    background: 
        center center /* background-position */
        url(//placehold.it/100/f00) /* background-image */
        red /* background-color */;
}
.box4 {
    background: 
        red /* background-color */
        url(//placehold.it/100/f00) /* background-image */
        center center /* background-position */;
}
```

Comment: however there is a question like this in the dumps, and the "correct" answer should be `CoPoSiROCAI`... all this is confusing...

Comment: from W3C docs "first sets ‘background-origin’ and the second ‘background-clip’": http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-backgrounds/#the-background

Answer (score 1):

The correct order specified by Microsoft is:

- color
- position
- size
- repeat
- origin
- clip
- attachment
- image

Answer (score 0):

I have learnt NOT to use the `background` shorthand property at all, because of the following reasons:

1. Mixed Implementation across browsers and editors
2. It sets missing properties to their initial values - this will overwrite any previously set values
3. Some properties share the same values, and this causes a lot of confusion.

In this particular case, choose clarity and consistency over performance. I should also mention that the performance gains are negligible.

Source: [Todd McLeod](https://twitter.com/todd_mcleod?lang=en)

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, however the OP asked a question about order, and not about performance, clarity or consistency. Thanks for your understanding and for the surely, a useful suggestion.

Comment: The same could be said for other shorthands, like `font`.